# Replace calculated negative values with 0 in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table my_table:

```
case_id    first_created  last_paid       submitted_time
   3456    2021-01-27     2021-01-29      2021-01-26 21:34:36.566023+00:00
   7891    2021-08-02     2021-09-16      2022-10-26 19:49:14.135585+00:00
   1245    2021-09-13     None            2022-10-31 02:03:59.620348+00:00
   9073    None           None            2021-09-12 10:25:30.845687+00:00
   6891    2021-08-03     2021-09-17      None
```

I created 2 new variables:

```sql
select *,
       first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date) as create_duration,
       last_paid-coalesce(submitted_time::date) as paid_duration 
from my_table;
```

The output:

```
  case_id    first_created  last_paid       submitted_time               create_duration paid_duration
   3456    2021-01-27     2021-01-29      2021-01-26 21:34:36.566023+00:00     1                3
   7891    2021-08-02     2021-09-16      2022-10-26 19:49:14.135585+00:00     -450            -405
   1245    2021-09-13     null            2022-10-31 02:03:59.620348+00:00     -412            null
   9073    None           None            2021-09-12 10:25:30.845687+00:00     null           null
   6891    2021-08-03     2021-09-17      null                                 null            null
```

My question is how can I replace new variables' value with 0, if it is smaller than 0?

The ideal output should look like:

```
  case_id    first_created  last_paid       submitted_time               create_duration paid_duration
   3456    2021-01-27     2021-01-29      2021-01-26 21:34:36.566023+00:00     1                3
   7891    2021-08-02     2021-09-16      2022-10-26 19:49:14.135585+00:00     0                0
   1245    2021-09-13     null            2022-10-31 02:03:59.620348+00:00     0               null
   9073    None           None            2021-09-12 10:25:30.845687+00:00     null             null
   6891    2021-08-03     2021-09-17      null                                 null             null
```

My code:

```sql
select  *,
        first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date) as create_duration,
        last_paid-coalesce(submitted_time::date) as paid_duration, 
        case
            when create_duration < 0 THEN 0
            else create_duration
        end as QuantityText
from my_table
```

Comment: Just use [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) over the entire expression.

Comment: @PM77-1 Hi ,thank you very much for your reply,I have just updated my code that with Case ,but it still not work ,can you give me more detail ,thank you very much!

Comment: @William you can't reference aliased values by their alias at this level - they'd have to be lower (in the source table, cte, subquery). Try [`greatest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST): `greatest(first_po_created-coalesce(submitted_timestamp::date),0) as create_duration, greatest(last_po_paid-coalesce(submitted_timestamp::date),0) as paid_duration`

Comment: @Zegarek thank you very much ,it works ,can you please post it as answer ,so that I can check it ,thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [`greatest(yourvalue,0)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)

Given `yourvalue` lower than `0`, `0` will be returned as the greater value:

```sql
select *
  ,greatest(0,first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date)) as create_duration
  ,greatest(0,last_paid    -coalesce(submitted_time::date)) as paid_duration
from my_table;
```

This will also change `null` values to `0`.

---

### [`case`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement

If you wish to keep the `null` results, you can resort to a regular [`case`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement. In order to alias your calculation you'll have to put it in a subquery or a cte:

```sql
select *
  ,case when create_duration<0 then 0 else create_duration end as create_duration_0
  ,case when paid_duration  <0 then 0 else paid_duration   end as paid_duration_0
from (
    select *
      ,first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date) as create_duration
      ,last_paid    -coalesce(submitted_time::date) as paid_duration
    from my_table ) as subquery;
```

---

### `(n+abs(n))/2`

If you sum a number with its absolute value, then divide by two (average them out), you'll get that same number if it was positive, or you'll get zero if it was negative because a negative number will always balance itself out with its absolute value:

- `(-1+abs(-1))/2 = (-1+1)/2 = 0/2 = 0`
- `( 1+abs( 1))/2 = ( 1+1)/2 = 2/2 = 1`

```sql
select *
  ,(create_duration + abs(create_duration)) / 2 as create_duration_0
  ,(paid_duration   + abs(paid_duration)  ) / 2 as paid_duration_0
from (
    select *
      ,first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date) as create_duration,
      ,last_paid    -coalesce(submitted_time::date) as paid_duration
    from my_table ) as subquery;
```

Which according to [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/02Mns2xB), is slightly faster than `case` and about as fast as `greatest()`, without affecting `null` values.

---

Note that `select *` pulls everything from below, so you'll end up seeing `create_duration` as well as `create_duration_0` - you can get rid of it by listing your desired output columns explicitly in the outer query. You can also rewrite it without subquery/cte, repeating the calculation, which will look ugly but in most cases planner will notice the repetition and evaluate it only once

```sql
select *
  ,case when first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date) < 0
        then 0
        else first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date)
   end as create_duration
  ,(abs(last_paid-coalesce(submitted_time::date))
    +   last_paid-coalesce(submitted_time::date) )/2 
       as paid_duration
from my_table;
```

or using a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES)

```sql
select *
  ,(select case when a<0 then 0 else a end 
    from (select first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date)) as alias(a) ) 
    as create_duration
  ,(select case when a<0 then 0 else a end 
    from (select last_paid-coalesce(submitted_time::date)) as alias(a) ) 
    as paid_duration
from my_table;
```

Neither of which help with anything in this case but are good to know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,is there anyway I can keep the null value of create_duration and paid_duration ,I don't want to covert it to 0 when it is null ,I only want to convert it to 0 when it is less than0.

Comment: @William Sure, with a regular `case`. See my update.

Comment: @William I stumbled upon an `(abs(val)+val)/2` purely arithmetic method that seems to be faster than `case`, about as fast as `greatest()`, while still keeping `null` values. It's added along with a link to [a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/02Mns2xB).

Comment: ,thank you so much,I learned a lot from your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on attaching your SQL Database to an ASP.NET app, you could create a c# script to query your database, and use the following:

```
Parameters.AddWithValue(‘Data You want to change’ ‘0’);
```

However, if your not using your SQL database with a ASP.NET app, this will not work.